# Accelerometer data logger method or application?

Tags: android, logging, accelerometer, sensors, microsoft-band

I am a graduate student working with the microsoft band 2 and its embedded sensors. I was just wondering if there was an application somewhere out there that I could use to essentially gather accelerometer data and log it into either a .txt file or even a spreadsheet from excel.

I really need some sort of method or application that would allow me to log the data and then play around with it later!

Thank you so much for all your help in advance!

Johnny

Comment: this seems very broad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is something like this what you are looking for? https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/band-laboratory/id1068043979?mt=8

Or, if you want to write a custom solution, you can download the SDK which has samples apps for subscribing to sensors from here: https://developer.microsofthealth.com/bandSDK

Comment: Yes that is definitely something I can work with. Thanks very much Mark!